# Xnvc process continues to run after remote user logs out

Tags: xfce, xrdp

Running xrdp and xfce. When remote users log out in the gui they continue to see the xfce logo on an otherwise blank screen. If they close the window there are no apparent errors.

But running htop on the host server shows an xvnc process still going for every session since last server reboot.

Thoughts?